# С помощью двух вложенных циклов выведите элементы этого массива в формате имя группы - имя юзера

Tags: php, массивы, циклы, foreach

Дан массив многомерный. Можно ли вывести так:
group1: 'user11', 'user12', 'user13', 'user43';
group2: 'user21', 'user22', 'user23';
У меня так не получается. Или я не правильно понял задание?
У меня выводит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$arr = [
    'group1'  => ['user11', 'user12', 'user13', 'user43'],
    'group2'  => ['user21', 'user22', 'user23'],
    'group3'  => ['user31', 'user32', 'user33'],
    'group4'  => ['user41', 'user42', 'user43'],
    'group5'  => ['user51', 'user52'],
];
foreach($arr as $key => $el1){
    foreach($el1 as $key2 => $elem){
            echo $key2. ': '.  $elem. '<br>';
}
echo '<br style>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = [
    'group1'  => ['user11', 'user12', 'user13', 'user43'],
    'group2'  => ['user21', 'user22', 'user23'],
    'group3'  => ['user31', 'user32', 'user33'],
    'group4'  => ['user41', 'user42', 'user43'],
    'group5'  => ['user51', 'user52'],
];

foreach($arr as $group => $students) {
    echo $group . ': ';
    foreach($students as $student) {
        echo $student . ', ';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Группы - это ключи элементов первого массива (внешнего), поэтому и выводить их надо в первом `foreach`